# Permanently adjust sound balance?

Tags: pulseaudio

My desktop stereo speakers seem to be louder on the right side. This doesn't matter for business sound, but for videos this is annoying. I always have to open the sound settings and adjust the balance slightly to the left.

That's a decent workaround but the setting seems to reset to center balance when the audio source ends. Note that the actual source software doesn't matter - YouTube, VLC, Plex, Banshee; they all do this and I have no reason to believe that the media application is causing this.

**How can I make this sound balance setting permanent?**

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/568981/349837).